# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, typeerror, nonetype

I couldn't find my mistake in this code below. If I say "return" instead of "print" in else part, code can not execute else part, it only makes calculations in if part. How can i fix this?

```
def calculatePerimeter(length, depth):
    if depth == 1:
        return 3 * length
    else:
        print (calculatePerimeter(length, depth-1) * (4/3)**(depth)) / ((4/3)**(depth-1))

calculatePerimeter(100, 3)
```

Comment: It works fine when I try it. `calculatePermimiter(100, 3)` returns `300`.

Comment: You are getting that error because of replacing `return` with `print`. If the function doesn't "return" anything in the else part, it returns `None`. And that's the `NoneType` that you get in the error message.

Comment: I tried all of the solutions that you said but 300 is not the correct answer. It gives you 300 because it can not execute else part at all. 300 is came from if part, i mean only base case of recursion.

Comment: Maybe the logic of recursion is wrong and problem is not about types. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value in the `else` clause, otherwise there's nothing to multiply (except when making the last call in the recursion). Then you need to call `print` when calling the function.

```
def calculatePerimeter(length, depth):
    if depth == 1:
        return 3 * length
    else:
        return (calculatePerimeter(length, depth-1) * (4/3)**(depth)) / ((4/3)**(depth-1))

print(calculatePerimeter(100, 3))
```